# Change UIView In Scroll View While / Update Scroll View Height - Swift 3 / Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a normal ViewController with a scroll view. In the scroll view are a few views a label and some buttons. Below all of that is a **UIView**. That **UIView** has multiple View Controllers being passed into it whenever one of the buttons is pressed. Each View Controller being passed into the **UIView** is a **different height**.

A picture to explain:

[image]

How do I adjust the Scroll View so it fits the new View Controller being passed in from the button press?

**UPDATE**
**Here's my code:**

```
 @IBAction func didPressTab(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let previousIndex = selectedIndex
    selectedIndex = sender.tag
    buttons[previousIndex].isSelected = false
    let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]
    previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    sender.isSelected = true
    let vc = viewControllers[selectedIndex]
    addChildViewController(vc)


    print("1. NEW VIEW HEIGHT \(vc.view.frame.height)")
    print("1. SCROLL VIEW HEIGHT \(scrollView.contentSize.height)")
    print("1. VIEW CONTROLLER HEIGHT \(self.view.frame.height)")
    print("1. CV HEIGHT \(contentView.frame.height)")
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    height = vc.view.frame.size.height
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    contentView.frame.size.height = vc.view.frame.height
    vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
    scrollView.contentSize.height = staticView.frame.height + height!
    contentView.addSubview(vc.view)



    print("2. NEW VIEW HEIGHT \(vc.view.frame.height)")
    print("2. SCROLL VIEW HEIGHT \(scrollView.contentSize.height)")
    print("2. VIEW CONTROLLER HEIGHT \(self.view.frame.height)")
    print("2. CV HEIGHT \(contentView.frame.height)")

    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)




}
```

I am able to get the height to change, but it just ends up making the UIView the size of a normal VC (667) which is not what I need because some of the ViewControllers are only 450 in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

**Preface:**
View Controllers have an assumed size. (the size of your phone's screen). That's why whenever I presented a view added a view to the UIView it was always 667 -(iPhone 6 Screen Size). So in order to fix that I did this:

**Code:**

```
if selectedIndex == 0 {

        vc.view.frame.size.height = 480

    }

    if selectedIndex == 1 {

        vc.view.frame.size.height = 448

    }

    if selectedIndex == 2 {

        vc.view.frame.size.height = 715

    }

    if selectedIndex == 3 {

        vc.view.frame.size.height = 480

    }
```

This was placed inside the IBAction. Right after **vc** is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You must recalculate the height of the scroll view content size whenever the embedded view controller changes.
The new height is image view height + buttons container height + content view height.
Obviously you must adapt the height of your container view too.

Comment: I have posted my code. I have done what you have mentioned and the height does change just not the right size, and it is the same for every view despite their varying heights.